# How Can I Upload a New Theme in WSO2?

Tags: themes, customization, wso2-api-manager

I have been trying to change the theme of my WSO2 store. 
It would only allow me to customize CSS and images. I want to apply a new structure to the theme.

Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on which version you are using.

If you are using WSO2 Cloud. You have to create a zip file with the custom css and upload it on the platform.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/APICloud/Customize+the+API+Store+Theme

If you are using WSO2 Local server then you will have to follow certain steps shown in the link below.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Adding+a+New+API+Store+Theme